# Disable thumbnails on Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, thumbnails

I am trying to obtain the highest performance from my Xubuntu system, disabling anything that I don't need.

How can I disable thumbnails on Xubuntu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh well, I figured it out. Open a File Manager window, go to Edit -> Preferences, and set Show Thumbnails to Never.

Answer (score 2):

The way I took care of it is this:

```
chmod -R -w ~/.thumbnails
```

I've never had another thumbnail since, no matter the program or preferences.